# Find list of strings that matches a pattern that start with a special character « and end with a special character »

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Given the text:

«Name» has an account on the bank «Bank Name»

Expected Output: ['Name', 'Bank Name']

I need Regex to get this list of matched strings. Please help me.

Comment: Can you share some code and input data?

Answer (score 1):

You can `match` using unicode and `replace` the unicodes later

[`Unicode finder`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)

```js
let str = `«Name» has an account on the bank «Bank Name»`

let final = str.match(/\u00AB.*?\u00BB/gu).map(v=>v.replace(/\u00AB|\u00BB/g,''))

console.log(final)
```

---

Alternatively you can use `exec` and get the value from captured group

```js
let str = `«Name» has an account on the bank «Bank Name»`
let final = []
let reg = /\u00AB(.*?)\u00BB/gu

while ((arr = reg.exec(str)) != null) {
  final.push(arr[1])
}

console.log(final)
```